civiRules: Difference between "Group is added" and "Contact is added to group"
Can someone explain the difference between these two triggers?
I had a rule using "Contact is added to group", but from what I could tell, it seems that each time the contact record was updated, the civiRule was being triggered.
I tried another rule for "Group is added", but that rule never seems to be triggered...

Group is added means when a group itself is created.

I have not heard of the issue with the "contact is added to group" being fired everytime a contact is updated before. Is this the only rule you have configured or do you have more? What version of CiviCRM are you on and what version of Civirules are you using?

I have civiCRM 5.75.1 and civiRules 3.12. I have 4 rules configured, two with "Group is added" and two with "Contact is added to Group". What I'm trying to do is send a contact a followup email after they register for an event. One of the profiles for the event adds the contact to a mailing list group.

I will try to reproduce your error on my local installation
